# What does the colorized text mean in ATOM Code Editor?

Tags: javascript, text, colors, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I understand JavaScript. But I know what the red, yellow and purple colorized text means in ATOM.

I guess those are grouped by specific JavaScript data but I'm not sure.

Do the colorized codes have any other meaning beside readability?

I would like to get some articles to learn about those if I could.

Thanks

[image]

(I didn’t change anything. From the picture this is the default code colors when you downloaded and start ATOM for the first time.)

Comment: > Do the colorized codes have any other meaning beside readability?
Nope. They are just theme colors to make things pretty and readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is purely aesthetical and doesn't change a thing in your actual code. It just makes it easier to read while you're programming.
The keyword here is [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting). There are many color schemes out there to help you getting a faster overview over your code.
You can also change the color palette in ATOM's settings if needed.